Array index out of bounds for a 1D array
I am trying to make a program that performs some sorting on a 1D Array, but I am unable to get the program running properly. I am aware of array lists but I do not want to use array lists here.
I would appreciate it if no changes were made to other parts of the program aside from things regarding the array
The code doesn't have to be flexible so instead of finding out how many lines are there in the code for the array dimensions i manually asked the user to input it instead
I can get the code compiled without errors now but when the program is run I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
Which I do not get because there are 5 entries in the csv file, and I input in the number of entries as 5, and i know the indexing is the array is 0-4, but it gives the same error when i input the number of entries as 4? So I do not really get what exactly is out of bounds here?
Data stored in CSV file:
Lana,20,6.3
Daniel,30,2.8
Lucas,29,4.9
Henry,19,8.2
Johnny,59,5.3

Code:
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class personProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numOfEntries;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many entries are there in the file?");
        numOfEntries = sc.nextInt();        
                
        readFile("PersonStorage.csv", numOfEntries);
        
    }

        public static void readFile(String pFileName, int numOfEntries)
    {   
        FileInputStream fileStream = null;
        InputStreamReader rdr;
        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        int lineNum;
        String line;
        
        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(pFileName);
            rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
            lineNum = 0;
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            Person[] persons = new Person[numOfEntries];

            while(line != null)
            {
                lineNum++;
                processLine(line, lineNum, persons);
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
            }
                    fileStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException errorDetails)
            { 
            if(fileStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileStream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ex2)
                { }
            }
            System.out.println("Error in fileProcessing: " + errorDetails.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void processLine(String csvRow, int lineNum, Person[] persons)
    {
        String[] data;
        data = csvRow.split(",");
        int lineLength = data.length;
        String name = data[0];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        double time = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);



        persons[lineNum] = new Person(name, age, time);


        //this is me testing
        System.out.print(persons[lineNum].getName());

    }


}



What errors are you encountering?

why do you expect rows to be usable in processLine?

@Vlam I have updated the question with the error I got, sorry about that

@BIBOO unit nice holo fan but i know that is kind of stupid of me, i was wondering about that too and if i should make it a global variable instead.. I changed the declarations of the array and rows/cols to inside processLine now but in that case will be array be able to be used outside of the method? I also edited my post for my current code and error

instead of focusing on global variables (bad practice unless its really absolutely needed) you should use function parameters to pass arguments (row here) to places its needed

Yeah so that was why i was recluctant on doing that, but holy i am an idiot i forgot about the parameters and stuff, thank you for that

Also, good practice -> try-with-resources. The array out of bounds exception is due to zero indexing. This Person[][] persons = new Person[rows][cols]; is fine, you are just declaring dimensions. This persons[rows][0] = new Person(name, age, time); is not fine. you are accessing an index that does not exist

Thank you so much for the input again, however I don’t quite understand about the indexing? Why doesnt the index exist? And in that case, what is correct way I should put the data from the csv file into the array?

Does this answer your question? What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?

I do get the general idea of it but I don't get why it appears on my code? I edited the post with the newly updated code after your suggestions, but I still get the same error when the program is run

(1-) Why did you delete your previous question on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78445599/131872 ??? You were given a suggestion on how to add debug code to your class to solve the problem? Where is the debug code. If you add the debug code it will be obvious that your index starts at 1 and not 0.

This used to be a different question and i kept editing it until it became this question but decided it was better to make a new post, so the newer post got closed (the one that u answered) and thanks to your help to open my blind eyes i fixed my code so i thought since it was closed i should just delete it… sorry about the confusion

Check the code, if this you want
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile("./PersonStorage.csv");
    }

    public static void readFile(String pFileName) {
        File file = new File(pFileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist: " + pFileName);
            return;
        }

        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
            Person[] persons = new Person[lines.size()];
            int index = 0;
            for (String line : lines) {
                processLine(line, persons, index++);
            }
            System.out.println("Processed " + persons.length + " persons");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to read file: " + pFileName);
        }
    }

    private static void processLine(String csvRow, Person[] persons, int index) {
        if (csvRow == null || csvRow.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        String[] data = csvRow.split(",");
        String name = data[0];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        double time = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);

        persons[index] = new Person(name, age, time);
        //this is me testing
        System.out.println(persons[index]);
    }
}


Thank you! This helped me a lot, I did keep some things in my code though so I still have the array of of bounds error T_T

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It's not clear why you want an array instead of the far more flexible List. Also, it's not a 2D array you want, but a 1D one, in which each element is a Person.
This is very simple if you give Person a helper method. Several class in the Java API have a valueof method that will statically return an instance from some parameter or other. You need public static Person valueOfCsv(String csvLine) in the class Person. That will enable you to do the following:
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.IOException;

public class People {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(readPeople(Path.of(args[0]))));
    }

    public static Person[] readPeople(Path peopleFile) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(peopleFile).
            map(Person::valueOfCsv).
            toArray(Person[]::new);
    }
}

Output:

[name=Lana,age=20,time=6.30, name=Daniel,age=30,time=2.80, name=Lucas,age=29,time=4.90, name=Henry,age=19,time=8.20, name=Johnny,age=59,time=5.30]


Thank you for the input! I can't believe i was an idiot and believed I need a 2D array all along...
